# Why do some .NET projects use an N- prefix in their name?

Tags: .net, naming-conventions

Probably a silly question, because I assume the N stands for ".NET", though I could be wrong. I'm interested in where this naming convention got started.

Examples:

> [NHibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/343.html)
>   [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/)
>   [NCover](http://www.ncover.com/)
>   [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/)
>   [Ninject](http://ninject.org/) (I realize this is supposed to be a play on "ninja", but it still fits)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

usually it means that original project (without N) was done for dome different language/framework. F. e. NHibernate was inspired by Hibernate for Java. So N means .net. For NUnit there is a whole family, like pyUnit, JUnit, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The same reason why Apple uses "i".

**Brand recognition.**

You immediately know it's a Microsoft .NET project.